# In Azure Pipelines, can I download a generated Azure CLI script?

Tags: azure-pipelines

In an Azure DevOps pipeline, I have an Azure CLI task running a PowerShell script:

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(azureServiceConnection)'
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      $foo = az rest --method GET --uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/000000-00000-00000-00000' | ConvertFrom-Json
      ... // etc
```

The pipeline run log gives me the path to the generated script file:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe 
  -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted 
  -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1665123106628.ps1'"
```

Can I somehow download the generated script `D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1665123106628.ps1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the logs, we could see the cli script file is located with the path of "D:\a_temp"

So in my test, manage to get the script with steps below.

1.I define a variable with below (in case that if you use other type of agents, the path will be different).
[image]

2.Add a task of "Publish build artifats", and set the path to publish with below
[image]

3.With the success, you could see the published artifact in the pipeline summary page.
[image]

4.Click in and below is your generated script
[image]

With below is the full yaml.

```
pool:

  name: Azure Pipelines

variables:

  cliscriptpath: 'D:\a\_temp'

 

steps:

- task: AzureCLI@2

  displayName: 'Azure CLI '

  inputs:

    azureSubscription: '***)'

    scriptType: ps

    scriptLocation: inlineScript

    inlineScript: 'az account show'

 

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1

  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'

  inputs:

    PathtoPublish: '$(cliscriptpath)'
```

​